# ETags for server-side rendered pages that contain CSP nonce

Tags: html, express, browser-cache, content-security-policy, etag

I have a server-side-rendered React app and Node/Express so far were able to generate the correct, stable [ETags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag), allowing for taking advantage of client-side caching.

Additionally, generated HTML contains fragments of render-blocking (above-the-fold) CSS and JS *inlined* as `<script>` and `<style>` tags for faster client-side first renders (as promoted by [Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-blocking-css) and its PageSpeed and Lighthouse tools).

Now I want to enable [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) and I provide a `nonce` as an attribute to those `<script>` and `<style>` tags on every page request, to avoid `unsafe-inline` violations. However, ever-changing nonce makes ETags to change on every request as well. HTML is never cached and every request hits my Express server.

Is there a way to combine simultaneously:

- inlined CSS and JS
- CSP features (that is `nonce`, or similar)
- ETags or alternatives

?

So far I see a contradiction between current performance vs security guidelines.

Are there equivalents to CSP nonce or can CSP nonce be provided while keeping HTML intact? Is there a way to otherwise cache pages that contain CSP nonce?

Ideally, I would like a solution to be contained within the Express server, without resorting to tinkering with my reverse proxy config, but any options are welcome.

Comment: I think that using hashes instead of nonces would be the way to handle this.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Thanks. Indeed, `scrpt-src '<hash-algorithm>-<base64-value>'` could be a way to go. Do you know how CSP hashes compare to [SRI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity)? What about browser support? It's a bit scary to let nonces go entirely. Certainly a security/performance trade off.

Comment: I don't have any special insight into browser support, but [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src) shows it as having the same support as nonces (i.e. part of CSP 2.0). I don't see any security downside, cryptographic hashing is very secure (that is, it would be infeasible for an attacker to insert another inline script with the same hash value).

Comment: As far as the use of nonces vs hashes, https://csp.withgoogle.com/docs/strict-csp.html recommends using nonces — and implicitly in preference over hashes — though https://csp.withgoogle.com/docs/faq.html#static-content explains how to use hashes instead for a case where nonces can’t be used. But see also https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#security-considerations, which contains some warnings about the use of nonces.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Good catch! It seems so far that it's better to use both, hashes and nonces. That means ETags are loosing the ground. Maybe I just get rid of them and provision some more compute for Express :)  <br/> To add another argument in defense of nonces: you cannot use hashes when the script content is dynamic ([link](https://www.troyhunt.com/locking-down-your-website-scripts-with-csp-hashes-nonces-and-report-uri/#usingnonces)). Dynamic script content is wrong on so many ways, and I don't have it, but who knows, maybe they have their valid usecases.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to leave the whole content generation and caching to web application (Node in your case) and CSP nonce generation to front-end webserver (e.g. Nginx). I have implemented it with Django which does page caching with `ETag`, does all the `Vary` header logic etc and the HTML it produces contains such a static CSP nonce placeholder:

```
< script nonce="+++CSP_NONDE+++"> ... </script>
```

This placeholder is then filled in by Nginx using `ngx_http_subs_filter_module`:

```
sub_filter_once off;
sub_filter +++CSP_NONCE+++ $ssl_session_id;
add_header Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'nonce-$ssl_session_id'";
```

I have seen solutions using an additional Nginx module to generate a truly unique random nonce for each request but I believe it's an overkill and I'm just using TLS session identifier, which is unique per each connecting client and may be cached for some time (e.g. 10 minutes) depending on your Nginx configuration.

Just make sure the web application returns uncompressed HTML as Nginx won't be able to do string substitution.

Comment: This method is very dangerous, because it allows an attacker to include XSS (including your placeholder) which will be replaced with valid nonces by the webserver. This is the very scenario which you are trying to defend against.